# How to debug PostgreSQL trigger error "query has no destination for result data"?

Tags: postgresql

I have three table, like this:

data_buku table

```
+----+----------+----------------+
| kode_buku  |  *  | *  |  stock |
+----+----------+----------------+
| 111        | *   | *  |  50    |
| 222        | *   | *  |  50    |
| 333        | *   | *  |  50    |
| 444        | *   | *  |  50    |
| 555        | *   | *  |  50    |
| 666        | *   | *  |  50    |
+----+-------+-----+----+--------+
```

data_pinjam table

```
+---------------+----------------------------+
| no_transaksi  |  kode_buku  | *  |  jumlah |
+---------------+-------------+----+---------+
| 1             | 111         | *  |   3     |
| 1             | 222         | *  |   2     |
| 1             | 333         | *  |   4     |
+---------------+-------------+----+---------+
```

data_kembali table

```
+---------------+-----+----+---------+
| no_transaksi  |  *  | *  |  status |
+---------------+-----+----+---------+
| 1             | *   | *  |   back  |
+---------------+-----+----+---------+
```

From my Tables, I create a function and trigger on table data_kembali. While Insert query to table data_kembali, function will make action to sum jumlah on table data_pinjam where no_transaksi in table data_kembali same with data_pinjam, and will update stock in table data_buku. Each rows with same kode_buku values. Stock + Jumlah.

I have create function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION kembali()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
CURRENT_STOK INT4;
r data_pinjam%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

FOR r IN
   SELECT *
   FROM   data_pinjam p
   WHERE  p.no_transaksi = new.no_transaksi
LOOP
   select CURRENT_STOK stock from data_buku where kode_buku = r.kode_buku;
   CURRENT_STOK = CURRENT_STOK + r.jumlah;
   UPDATE data_buku SET STOCK = CURRENT_STOK WHERE kode_buku = r.kode_buku;   
END LOOP;

UPDATE data_pinjam SET status = 'kembali' WHERE no_transaksi = new.no_transaksi;

update data_transaksi set status = 'kembali' where no_transaksi = new.no_transaksi;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

but while running, get output

```
ERROR: query has no destination for result data
SQL state: 42601
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
Context: PL/pgSQL function kembali() line 13 at SQL statement
```

Can someone advise me regarding this trigger and function for update with loop?

Comment: "query has no destination for result data" seems a clear error message. Often, providing an extra `AS <alias/name>` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement in the cursor loop requires a destination for the selected value:

```
SELECT stock
  INTO CURRENT_STOK
  FROM data_buku 
  WHERE kode_buku = r.kode_buku;
```

The variable `CURRENT_STOK` would also need to be declared (before the `BEGIN`).

But perhaps the intent of the cursor for loop is this?

```
UPDATE data_buku
  SET STOCK = STOCK + r.jumlah
  WHERE kode_buku = r.kode_buku;
```